# Anyone know why the DISTINCT keyword in MYSQL isnt working here?

Tags: mysql

[image: 1]

I understand that they aren't exactly duplicate rows, but how do I specify the DISTINCT command to only check for the first column.
Thanks in advance

Comment: *how do I specify the DISTINCT command to only check for the first column* - you don't, *distinct* applies to the entire row.

Comment: Please don't embed images showing your questions. Instead use text. You can indent it four spaces. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
FROM Employees JOIN Departments 
          ON Employees.dep_id = Departments.dep_id
```

Without an `ON` clause a JOIN is a Cartesian join, yielding every possible combination of rows in the two tables.

`DISTINCT` is not useful for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT works on the entire row returned, not a single attribute.

```
(Frank, William, Sales)
```

...is distinct from...

```
(Frank, William, IT)
```

...even if some of the attributes are the same.

PS- please include quoted code and results instead of a link.